# Fedora multiplies in grub after dnf update

Tags: linux, fedora, grub2

I run `sudo dnf update` a couple of times, and it worked well. But now this is what I get in GRUB

[image: Multiple Fedora versions]

It looks like it creates a separate Fedora for every version. I ran

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

multiple times but it didn't help. That's what i got back

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.12.11-300.fc26.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.12.11-300.fc26.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.12.9-300.fc26.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.12.9-300.fc26.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.11.8-300.fc26.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.11.8-300.fc26.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-206e415ec0e847f28f01e95ee6400ce1
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-0-rescue206e415ec0e847f28f01e95ee6400ce1.img
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
done
```

They are available here:

```
[iron@localhost boot]$ ls | grep vmlinuz
vmlinuz-0-rescue-206e415ec0e847f28f01e95ee6400ce1
vmlinuz-4.11.8-300.fc26.x86_64
vmlinuz-4.12.11-300.fc26.x86_64
vmlinuz-4.12.9-300.fc26.x86_64
```

I may be able to delete then from here the `/boot/` folder, but I'm not sure if it won't mess smth up.

UPDATE:
I decided to move the files to a different folder so now updating the GRUB gives me this

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.12.11-300.fc26.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.12.11-300.fc26.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-206e415ec0e847f28f01e95ee6400ce1
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-0-rescue-206e415ec0e847f28f01e95ee6400ce1.img
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
done
```

I tried restarting it, and it booted up ok, but in GRUB screen did NOT change. Any ideas what to do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fedora gives you the option to boot the most recent or any older kernel that your system has installed. This is a really important feature when one kernel, after an update for example, lets your computer behave weirdly. You have 2+*x* backup kernels.

The number of kernels that Fedora will keep is defined in `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`. The parameter is called `installonly_limit=x`, where x is the number of kernels installed at once.

e.g.,

> installonly_limit=6

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out that's normal. More info in a comment here:

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/110941/how-to-sorten-bootloader-list/

> Actually, from what you're showing, it only has three Fedora kernels listed, and even if you do nothing, it will stay that way, with the oldest kernel removed every time a new one's installed. This is a safety feature in case there's a problem with a new kernel because you should always have two known good kernels to use instead. My advice is to simply leave things alone and don't worry about it. — [sideburns](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/users/3027/sideburns/) (CC-BY-SA)